# loop to create a new ImageIcon - java

Tags: java, loops

i have this piece of code

```
ImageIcon[] Image = { 
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/1.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/2.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/3.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/4.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/5.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/6.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/7.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/8.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/9.gif"),
};
```

an d i tried with the code below replace the script above

```
    ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[9];

    for (int i = 1; i < image.length; i++) {
        new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/"+i+".gif");
    }
```

but the result is...any image is loaded. what is the error?

thanks

Comment: Unrelated error:  You are only counting from 1 to 8.

Comment: i will change in my code, it is an example, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put new images into array:

```
image[i] = new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/"+i+".gif");
```

Now it does the same thing as your old code.

Comment: Don't forget to change your indexing. Your images appear to index from 1. Java will index arrays from 0. You'll want to account for this in your code.

Comment: I would also like to point out that in my game development experience, your approach is going to lead to some complications. You can keep track of 10 images. You can't keep track of 1000 images. So, you're left with two options... naming your files, or keeping a registry of your files in code. Personally, I have a class that is essentially `class MyImageIcon { ImageIcon icon; String imageName; public MyImageIcon(File f) { icon = loadIconFromFile(f); imageName = f.replace(".jpg",""); }`

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    image[i] =new ImageIcon("../KingGame/src/game/img/"+(i+1)+".gif");
}
```